# Change a Wordpress Hook in Functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook

I'm attempting to replace a hook name so that my breadcrumb is removed from one location and added to another spot in the page. I'm using a child theme and I'd like to accomplish this within the functions.php of my child theme. What happens is that the function is removed from one location, and added to the new location, but it fires twice, so I have two breadcrumbs stacked on top of each other.

The parent theme function looks like this:

```html
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Breadcrumb display */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_action('woo_main_before','woo_display_breadcrumbs',10);
if (!function_exists( 'woo_display_breadcrumbs')) {
 function woo_display_breadcrumbs() {
  global $woo_options;
  if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_breadcrumbs_show'] ) && $woo_options['woo_breadcrumbs_show'] == 'true' && ! (is_home()) ) {
  echo '<section id="breadcrumbs">';
   woo_breadcrumbs();
  echo '</section><!--/#breadcrumbs -->';
  }
 } // End woo_display_breadcrumbs()
} // End IF Statement
```

And this is what I have in my functions.php file of the child theme.

```html
add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'remove_woo_display_breadcrumbs', 0 );

function remove_woo_display_breadcrumbs() {

    remove_action('woo_main_before','woo_display_breadcrumbs',10);
 
}


add_action('woo_content_before','woo_display_breadcrumbs',10);
```

By the way, this is the Mystile theme by Woo Themes. I'm really new to Hooks, so if you do have the answer, a short explanation of why would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first, to fix the problem you need to do the following:

```
remove_action('woo_main_before', 'woo_display_breadcrumbs', 10); // Removes from the original location
add_action('woo_content_before', 'woo_display_breadcrumbs', 10); // Adds to the new location
```

The '10' is the priority that a function runs for a particular action. Think of it like a slot.

So slot 0 is completely independent from slot 10.

All we're doing in the code sample above is taking `woo_display_breadcrumbs` out of one slot and inserting it into another.

I hope this helps.